# Placing Spaces Between the Titles of Plots

Tags: r, plotly, data-visualization

I made this pie chart in R:

```
# https://plotly.com/r/text-and-annotations/

    df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    df <- df[which(df$year==2007 & df$continent=='Asia'),]
    
    fig <- plot_ly(df, type='pie', labels = ~country, values = ~pop, textposition = 'inside')
    fig1 <- fig %>% layout(uniformtext=list(minsize=12, mode='hide'))
    
     fig1 <- fig1 %>% add_annotations(
        y=1.05, 
        x=0.5, 
        text="Countries of the World", 
        showarrow=F,
        font=list(size=15)
      )
```

[image]

Everything works fine here, but I notice that when I am working with my real data, the title of the pie chart and the actual pie chart always come very close to intersecting with each other - I would like to try and change this.

I was thinking if there might be a way to avoid this problem. I thought that perhaps I could add more space between the title and the actual pie chart to avoid this problem from happening. I found this post here ([how to adjust title space and plot plotly in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61689721/how-to-adjust-title-space-and-plot-plotly-in-r)) and tried to apply the advice that was suggested in the answer:

```
mrg <- list(l = 50, r = 50,
            b = 50, t = 50,
            pad = 20)

fig1 %>% layout(margin = mrg)
```

However, this has not seemed to add any space between the pie chart and the title of the pie chart.

- Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option making use of `layout` for the title and adjusting the spacing. Then, you can just adjust the margins to get the desired spacing.

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(df, type='pie', labels = ~country, values = ~pop, textposition = 'inside') %>% 
  layout(uniformtext=list(minsize=12, mode='hide')) %>% 
  layout(title = list(text = 'Countries of the World',
                      y=1.25, 
                      x=0.43, font=list(size = 30)),
         autosize = T, 
         margin=list( l = 50, r = 50, b = 100, t = 100,  pad = 4))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @ AndrewGB: Thank you so much for your answer! Is there an effective way to control the size of the plot? I find that when I am doing this, the size of this plot is always shrinking ... I tried to do this using the height/weight arguments, but I get an error message stating that "width/height in layout() is now deprecated". Do you have any ideas about this? Thank you so much!